# craete multiple apk for multiple customers android

Tags: android

I have Android application that needs to be delivered to multiple customers. For every customer I have different graphics(logo, text, app name, color) and configuration XML files.

At build time we should be able to specify the customer for which the application should be built. Then resources (like images and run-time configuration) appropriate for the specified client should be built into the app.

as of now i am newly to android. i have gone through some product flavor tutorial but unable to find out the way.

any help will be highly appreciated thank you

Comment: instead of generating multiple application you can show this thing in single app also make login base on login type display design or whatever you want

Comment: Check out Build Variant concept. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya i need to upload individual application with each customer on playstore.
Stallion i already gone to that but unable to get the concept

Comment: your customer have different category?

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya yes. each customer has their own brand need.

Comment: then check it as login time like flag if flag==abc go with this flow or design or flag==pqr go with another design or flow at start of application

Answer (score 0):

Build Variant is good option also as @Stallion suggested,Still
you can use multiple flavour in same project like main flavour under src folder ,

- Create multiple flavour for every customer.
- Every flavour will have its own java,res,manifest and assest folder under it,each manifest will have its launcher activity.
- There will be a common flavour main from which you will decide which customer's app need to launch

For example : You have 2 apps requirement B and C,and there will be a common flavour main.So from main flavour you will start another flavour like

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.example.B");
startActivity(i);
```

From here it'll go to module B's manifest and will launch the launcher activity.And similarly for C module also.